# Robot Framework unable to find the right address for a link

Tags: selenium, jupyter-notebook, robotframework

I'm running a Corona Jupyter notebook every day manually and want to automate this using Robot Framework.

Here is the code:

```
Library           RPA.Browser.Selenium

# ...

${result1}=    Open Using Run Dialog    C:/Python/runJupyter.bat    C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe
Open Browser    http://localhost:8888/?token=c08...    chrome    alias=chrome
Maximize Browser Window
Click Element    //span[contains(text(), 'Corona')]
Sleep    1s
Click Element    //span[contains(text(),"corona.ipynb")]
Sleep    3s
${handle}=    Switch Window    NEW # took me a while to find this
${title}=    Get Title
Log    ${title} # check if the right Tab is active
Pause Execution
# //*[contains(@id,"run_all_cells")] # error
# //a[contains(text(), 'Run All')] # also error
# //a[text()='Run All'] # also error
Click Element    //*[contains(@id,"run_all_cells")] # error
Pause Execution
```

Finally I want to `Run All` lines of the notebook. None of the xpath variants work even if I inspected the html code using chrome. The message I get is: `Message: element not interactable`

What is the right xpath for `Run All`?

EDIT: The section of interest looks as follows:

```
 <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cell</a>
                    <ul id="cell_menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li id="run_cell" title="Run this cell, and move cursor to the next one">
                            <a href="#">Run Cells</a></li>
                        <li id="run_cell_select_below" title="Run this cell, select below">
                            <a href="#">Run Cells and Select Below</a></li>
                        <li id="run_cell_insert_below" title="Run this cell, insert below">
                            <a href="#">Run Cells and Insert Below</a></li>
                        <li id="run_all_cells" title="Run all cells in the notebook">
                            <a href="#">Run All</a></li>
                        <li id="run_all_cells_above" title="Run all cells above (but not including) this cell">
                            <a href="#">Run All Above</a></li>
                        <li id="run_all_cells_below" title="Run this cell and all cells below it">
                            <a href="#">Run All Below</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
```

Comment: Hmm maybe it's just my configuration but I don't see option to run all on the main page - I have to go into the cell menu to get to it - are you sure you're not missing a step to click on this menu item?

e.g. Click Element  //*[@id="celllink"] followed by Click Element  //*[@id="run_all_cells"]/a

Comment: Hmmm, no, it doesn't work: Element with locator '//*[@id="cellink"]' not found. On the first "Stop Execution" I can manually click on "Run All" without focusing on the first cell, since the command executes all cells ;-)

Comment: Ah okay - Could you show some of the html from the page?

Comment: I edited the original post and added the html section of interest.

Comment: That's in a drop down, have you opened the drop down menu in the automation? I think it would be //*[@id="celll_menu"] or the dropdown toggle one above

Comment: I really thought that's it, but unfortunately: Click Element    //*[@id="cell_menu"] --> Message: element not interactable; BUT: it was the right hint. I changed it to: Click Element  //a[text()='Cell']. Now it works. If you add it as answer, I select it as solution and vote it up :-) ... Thank you!

Comment: Welcome :) Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an additional step required to open the drop down menu with `Click Element //a[text()='Cell']` before clicking the link element to "Run All"